# how to use Jquery UI bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to style the datatable just like twitter bootstrap and I came across twitter bootstrap jquery ui theme. After extracting, there were 4 files inside the css folder. These are

```
jquery.ui.1.9.2.ie.css
jquery.ui.1.10.0.ie.css
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css
jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css
```

I want to know which files should be inlcuded and what is the significance of each file.
I also do find that while implementing jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css only file, the dialog boxes header is not properly aligned. Is dialog boxes not properly aligned in the default theme?

Answer (score 0):

Include both the files & your alignment issue will be gone, i think 1.10.0. seems to be the latest version. So include

1. jquery.ui.1.10.0.ie.css
2. jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css

Also open these both files in an editor to view and understand the alignment and design.